# Get current page title in wikipedia

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia

Is there a way to get the page title in form of a magic word or parameter?

For example if a page title is Cats and I want to populate some parameters based on the title i'd like to put the "magic word" instead of writing 'Cats' everywhere.

Instead of: 
{{Hello | animal = Cats}}

id like to write
{{Hello | animal = get_page_title}}

edit: Found the answer
https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Magic_words#Page_names

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you've already said: there are a lot of magic words available to get the current page name or only a part of it: https://m.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Magic_words#Page_names